# Query String values not related to Active Forums don't survive the PostBack

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

Query String values not related to Active Forums don't survive the PostBack.

Example URL (before submit): http://www.example.com/activity/afv/post/aff/279/aft/20/afr/20/groupid/797?versiontest=123

URL (after submit): http://www.example.com/activity/aft/20/groupid/797#33 (versiontest parameter is missing).

How can I keep these query string parameters after postback?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @brykneval, I need to have the page after postback to have the value in the URL. How do you retrieve the stored string from ViewState and append it to the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the form's action to the raw url.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, @VDWWD, this gives me a 503 error... Also, in DNN the form's id is "Form", so I tried to change the code to "Form.Action = Request.RawUrl;" but same 503 error happened. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, next time label your question with `DotNetNuke`, that is kind of important in this situation. But that is also your problem. DNN handles the urls, and maybe active forums has it's own url rewriter.